# s4sdk, Neo or Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, s4hana

We are currently evaluating the SCP, the available SDKs and trying to find the right environment (Neo or CF) and the right setup for the following project requirements:

- Provision of an oData service
- Connecting S/4 (reading / writing)
- Persistence in SCP Hana DB
- SCP workflow integration
- SCP document service Integration
- Multitenancy capable

We find it hard to decide about the right setup (environment and SDK's):

- The "document" and "workflow" services are available in Neo.
  Is our assumption correct that our service-application must therefore run in Neo as well?
- The "SAP Cloud Platform SDK for Service Development" seems to us the right approach to implement OData services. However, the SDK is available for cloud foundry environment only.

Please give us some advice on

- What is the right environment for our requirements?
- Which SDK's could be used in order to implement it efficiently?

Answer (score 4):

(Disclaimer: I work in the team building the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK)

Khalid is right in that the document service and workflow are at the moment still only available in NEO, and that [OData provisioning with SAP Cloud Platform SDK for service development](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/10/17/introducing-the-sap-cloud-platform-sdk-for-service-development/) is only supported on Cloud Foundry.

We encourage our customers and partners to reach out to their SAP contact to find a solution: To increase visible demand for a solution not yet available or to find a workaround. Please reach out to your SAP contact!

Neo is still supported but we are planning to switch all apps to Cloud Foundry - meaning we build so that switching is easy. The main factor for this are the platform abstractions provided by the [SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK](https://www.sap.com/developer/topics/s4hana-cloud-sdk.html). It is built on top of the SAP Cloud Platform SDK and you get these features on top:

- [nice platform abstractions](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/19/deep-dive-3-cloud-platform-abstractions-in-the-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/) allowing you to switch between SAP Cloud Platform Cloud Foundry and Neo easily with only changing maven dependencies and recompiling
- [S/4HANA Cloud SDK virtual data model](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/21/step-4-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-calling-an-odata-service/) allowing you to write code like `new DefaultBusinessPartnerService().getAllCustomer()` and it transparently accesses the tenant-specific S/4HANA-backend
- [ruggedly built architecture using Hystrix](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/23/step-5-resilience-with-hystrix/)
- [integration pipeline-as-code](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline)
- fast track towards selling your extension in the SAP App Center partner store, see [Wieland's article on customer and partner enabling](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/27/connect-innovate-extend-enabling-customers-and-partners-with-the-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/)
- ...

Check out the [20+ tutorials and deep dives for the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/10/first-steps-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/).

The situation of the items in your list on Apr 10th, 2018 - let's keep this updated:

- Provision of an oData service: Supported on Cloud Foundry with [OData provisioning with SAP Cloud Platform SDK for service development](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/10/17/introducing-the-sap-cloud-platform-sdk-for-service-development/)
- Connecting S/4 (reading / writing): SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK with virtual data model: `new DefaultBusinessPartnerService().getAllCustomer()`
- Persistence in SCP Hana DB: Supported on Neo and Cloud Foundry
- SCP workflow integration: Currently still limited to Neo
- SCP document service Integration: Currently still limited to Neo
- Multitenancy capable: Neo and Cloud Foundry

Answer (score 2):

The "Document service" and "Workflow" only available in NEO environment on SAP Cloud Platform.

But Hana DB, OData service can use on both neo and cloud foundry environment.

> So, for your requirement, Neo would be a better choice.